# Problem installing IP-Filters MAC for transparent proxy

Tags: mac-osx, proxy, mac, squid, transparent-proxy

Am trying to compile squid to allow transparency using this command

```
./configure --enable-ipf-transparent
```

on a MAC mini running 10.5.8

am getting a error

```
WARNING: Cannot find necessary IP-Filter header files 
         Transparent Proxy support WILL NOT be enabled
```

How can i solve this, how can I install the IP headers file, I already have the installer (IP Filter 4.1.33) but which distribution do I use for a mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Mac OS X uses ipfw and not ipf (I know it looks the same [but it's not](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ipfw/2004-December/001583.html))

So use this command to configure your build. It's only available with [Squid 3.0](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.0/) and up.

```
./configure --enable-ipfw-transparent
```

I'd suggest enabling SSL support as well

```
./configure --enable-ipfw-transparent --enable-ssl
```